# Openservice functions for windows 7 and above operating system

Tags: c, windows-7

I wanted to know that is there any openservice functions like `SC_HANDLE` supported by Windows 7 and above, wherein I can write a **C** program to start a particular service in windows?

Comment: A quick search at MSDN on `SC_HANDLE` gave me [these results](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=sc_handle&pgArea=header&emptyWatermark=true&ac=2). Did you put any effort into trying to figure this out yourself before posting?

Comment: Thank you Sir, I will look into it.